# "ACM ICPC Team" challenge

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, python-3.x

I'm attempting [this question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/acm-icpc-team) on HackerRank, which states the follows:

> You are given a list of \$N\$ people who are attending ACM-ICPC World
>   Finals. Each of them are either well versed in a topic or they are
>   not. Find out the maximum number of topics a 2-person team can know.
>   And also find out how many teams can know that maximum number of
>   topics.
>
> Note Suppose \$a\$, \$b\$, and \$c\$ are three different people, then \$(a,b)\$ and
>   \$(b,c)\$ are counted as two different teams.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains two integers, \$N\$ and \$M\$, separated by a single
>   space, where \$N\$ represents the number of people, and M represents the
>   number of topics. \$N\$ lines follow. Each line contains a binary string
>   of length \$M\$. If the ith line's jth character is \$1\$, then the ith person
>   knows the jth topic; otherwise, he doesn't know the topic.

In my code below, I replaced \$N\$ with `ppl` and \$M\$ with `topics`.

```
ppl, topics = map(int, input().split())
knowledge = []

max_group = 0
max_topic = 0

for x in range(ppl):
    inp = input()
    x = [int(i) for i in inp]
    knowledge.append(x)

for x in range(ppl):
    for y in range(x+1, ppl):
        current_topic = 0

        for z in range(topics):
            if knowledge[x][z] | knowledge[y][z] == 1:
                current_topic += 1

        if current_topic == max_topic:
            max_group += 1
        elif current_topic > max_topic:
            max_topic = current_topic
            max_group = 1

print(max_topic)
print(max_group)
```

The solution above should return the correct outputs (passed three test cases), but there are simply **way** too many loops (5, if I am correct). What are some ways that I can reduce the amount of loops and bring the run-time down?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a better than \$(O(N^2M))\$ (that is, brute force) solution; however an asymptotic constant could be improved significantly.

First, I recommend to represent an individual knowledge as an integer rather than a list. This way computing a team knowledge is a matter of a single bitwise `or`, and a number of topics covered is the amount of bits set.

To obtain an integer representation of knowledge, recall that `int()` takes base as a second argument:

```
    for _ in range(ppl):
        knowledge.append(int(input(), 2))
```

Then analyze a combined team of `x, y` knowledge as

```
    team_topics = bit_count(knowledge[x] | knowledge[y])
```

There are many ways to implement `bit_count`. [Here](http://blog.philippklaus.de/2014/10/counting-bits-set-to-1-in-bytes-with-python-popcount-or-hamming-weight/) is a good place to start.

Observations not related to performance:

- **Naming** is not particularly good. I expect `current_topic` to be a loop index running through topics, not the count of topics covered by team. Similarly, `max_topic` is named as if it represents the maximal index in topics table.
- **Dummy loop variable** (`x` in the input loop) is by convention denoted by `_`. Seeing `_` the reader *knows* it is dummy, and doesn't look for how it might be used in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use int(input(),2) to convert those binary numbers into its decimal equivalent

```
for x in range(ppl):
    knowledge.append(int(input(),2))
```

It's better to use count()

Here is the code:

```
ppl, topics = map(int, input().split())
knowledge = []
pairs_list=[]

for x in range(ppl):
    knowledge.append(int(input(),2))

for x in range(ppl):
    for y in range(x+1, ppl):
        pairs_list.append(bin(knowledge[x] | knowledge[y]).count('1'))

print(max(pairs_list))
print(pairs_list.count(max(pairs_list)))
```